# C# windows event viewer

Tags: c#, log4net

I want to log the errors from my C# app in Windows Event Viewer using log4net with the EventLogAppender (the errors must be logged under the Application log)
I have a log4net.config class with this code

```
<configuration>
<configSections>
    <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net, Version=2.0.8.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=669e0ddf0bb1aa2a" />
</configSections>
  <log4net>
   <appender name="EventLogAppender" type="log4net.Appender.EventLogAppender">
       <applicationName value="MySource" />
       <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
         <conversionPattern value="{%level} {%date} – %message%newline" />
       </layout>
    </appender>

  <root>
     <level value="DEBUG" />
     <appender-ref ref="EventLogAppender" />
  </root>
  </log4net>
</configuration>
```

In AssemblyInfo I added the following line

```
[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(ConfigFile = "log4net.config", Watch=true)]
```

Then in my Program class

```
class Program
{
  static log4net.ILog log = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);

  static void Main(string[] args)
  {
     string name=null;
     try
     {
         Console.WriteLine("Name : " + name.ToString());
     }
     catch (NullReferenceException nullException)
     {
        log.Error("Name is NULL", nullException);
     }
}
}
```

I have to mention that I used power shell to create a new EventLog called "MySource"

The problem is that I receive the following error:

```
log4net:ERROR Could not create Appender [EventLogAppender] of type [log4net.Appender.EventLogAppender]. Reported error follows.
System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'log4net.Appender.EventLogAppender' from assembly 'log4net, Version=2.0.8.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=669e0ddf0bb1aa2a'.
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.GetType(QCallAssembly assembly, String name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, ObjectHandleOnStack type, ObjectHandleOnStack keepAlive, ObjectHandleOnStack assemblyLoadContext)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.GetType(String name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase)
   at log4net.Util.SystemInfo.GetTypeFromString(Assembly relativeAssembly, String typeName, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase)
   at log4net.Repository.Hierarchy.XmlHierarchyConfigurator.ParseAppender(XmlElement appenderElement)
log4net:ERROR Appender named [EventLogAppender] not found.
```

Comment: You could try adding this key to enable log4net debugging to the <appSettings> section of your app.config file: <add key="log4net.Internal.Debug" value="true"/>     This should show you if log4net has any issues setting up the appender.

Comment: Works fine on my machine. This is .net framework? .net core? .net compact framework?

Comment: @Peska I am using .NET Core 3.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Latest version of log4net (2.0.8 as of today) is implementing .net standard 1.3: https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/release-notes.html.

In .net standard 1.3 `EventLogAppender` is not supported: https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/framework-support.html#netstandard-1.3

If you want to use `EventLogAppender`, you will have to switch to .net framework.